# Haskell read function overloading with two inputs

Tags: haskell, overloading

In my haskell program I have a list that represents a database in `[(key, value)]` format. For example this is a valid database: `[("key1", "value1"), ("key2", "value2"), ("key3", "value3")]`. The *key* and *value* data will always have *String* type.

My question is: is it possible to code the **reading operation** by overloading the **read function** and using that in this way: `read dbList "key1"`? If yes how can I solve this problem? The output needs to be `("not found","value data for key not exists")` or `("found", "value1")`.

I`ve looked up how can I solve this but all that I found is how to use read function to one input parameter and how to define a new type in order to create an instance of the read for that particular type if it is needed. But I am still curious if I can overload somehow the read function with two input paramaters.

Comment: `read :: Read a => String -> a` is for creating values of a specific type from a string representation, not for performing database lookups.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. My boss asked from me to use the **read** function with expected code examples and I wanted to be sure if this is possible because I don`t find find any ways to resolve it.

Comment: Is he aware of the `Read` class? `read` itself cannot be overloaded, because it is not actually defined by the `Read` class.

Comment: Maybe he just write it for example givings, probably he didn't analyzed it deeply. I think it's ok if it won't be **read** char by char. I was just curious if it's possible before act.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, I will present a way to do it using `read`. However, this is very unusual and I would consider it a bad idea, since you can just use `lookup`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

type DB = [(String, String)]

instance Read (DB -> (String, String)) where
  readsPrec _ = \key -> let
    f db = case lookup key db of
      Just x -> ("found", x)
      Nothing -> ("not found", "data for " ++ key ++ " does not exist")
    in [(f, "")]
```

Here we define an instance of `Read` for the type `DB -> (String, String)`. Recall that the `read` function has type `Read a => String -> a`, so this instance gives us an overload of `read` of type `String -> DB -> (String, String)`.

Our instance defines the `readsPrec` function, which has type `Read a => Int => ReadS a`, where `ReadS a` is an alias for `String -> [(a, String)]`. So our `readsPrec` implementation must have type `Int -> String -> [(DB -> (String, String), String)]`. We don’t care about the “precedence” argument, so we ignore it with `_`. And we only care about returning a single result in this instance, so we simply return `[(f, "")]` where `f` is a function of type `DB -> (String, String)` that performs the `lookup` of the `key` in its argument `db`.

Now we can use this instance like so:

```
> read "foo" [("foo", "bar")] :: (String, String)
("found","bar")

> read "baz" [("foo", "bar")] :: (String, String)
("not found","data for baz does not exist")
```

Again I would stress that this is an unusual instance that may cause confusion in real code—you should just use `lookup` directly.

Answer (score 4):

The function you want is `lookup`, which is part of the Prelude.

```
> :t lookup
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
> let dbList = [("key1", "value1")]
> lookup "key1" dbList
Just "value1"
> lookup "key2" dbList
Nothing
```

If you really need the output in the tuple form you show, you can pattern-match on the result.

```
case lookup dbList someKey of
    Just x -> ("found", x)
    Nothing -> ("not found", "data for " ++ key ++ " does not exist")
```